# Count calls to apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my project, a particular remote server A is called from another application B. The application B is distributed on X nodes. The application B has a single place where the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and HttpClient are created. However the HttpClient.execute() method is all over the codebase in application B.

For telemetry purposes, I want to track the concurrent number of calls made by each of the X nodes to the remote server A. I am using StatsD client to increment and decrement a counter for keeping track of the calls. The idea is to increment a counter when the call starts, and decrement it when the call succeeds, fails or times out.

My first thought is to use HttpRequestInterceptor and HttpResponseInterceptor to increment and decrement the counter. However in case of timeouts , there is no response, and hence the HttpResponseInterceptor does not get called.

Does anyone has a workaround for this issue, or a better solution? I know the problem is simpler if we can annotate the methods which do  HttpClient.execute(), however that is a expensive solution given the size of codebase. Hence I am looking for a better alternative. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a custom request execution interceptor instead of protocol interceptors

```
final AtomicLong concurrentExchangeCount = new AtomicLong(0);

final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = new HttpClientBuilder() {

    @Override
    protected ClientExecChain decorateMainExec(final ClientExecChain mainExec) {
        return (route, request, clientContext, execAware) -> {
            concurrentExchangeCount.incrementAndGet();
            try {
                return mainExec.execute(route, request, clientContext, execAware);
            } finally {
                concurrentExchangeCount.decrementAndGet();
            }
        };
    }
};
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
```